# Visual Studio Graphics Debugger - Shader Edit and Apply is not available

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, directx-11, direct3d11

Visual studio graphics debugger - HLSL debugging is not working for me. I can't even open the shader file in graphics debugger.

If I select a draw call and then try to open up the shader shown in pipeline stages or pixel history I get the following error message -

> Shader Edit and Apply is not available for this shader. This can be caused by building shaders without debug information or with an unsupported compiler. "

Followed by this error log in compiler output window -

> Error parsing the Shader Xml: System.Xml.XmlException: Name cannot
>   begin with the '<' character, hexadecimal value 0x3C. Line 4777,
>   position 696.    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
>   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String[] args)    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseAttributes()    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElement()    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()    at
>   System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r)    at
>   System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r, LoadOptions o)
>   at System.Xml.Linq.XElement.ReadElementFrom(XmlReader r, LoadOptions
>   o)    at System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions
>   options)    at System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Load(TextReader textReader,
>   LoadOptions options)    at
>   Microsoft.VsPixPkg.ShaderViewer.Parser.Parse(String xmlContents,
>   List`1 files, String& disassemblyContents, String& entryPoint, String&
>   modelAndType, String& defines, Boolean& disableOptimizations, String&
>   flags, String& FileGPUdisassemblyContents, String&
>   LiveGPUdisassemblyContents)    at
>   Microsoft.VsPixPkg.ShaderViewer.Parser.ParseShaderData(UInt32 address,
>   String cachePath, ObjectGraph graph, String xmlContents, List`1&
>   sourceFiles, List`1& fileContents, String& disassemblyContents,
>   String& entryPoint, String& shaderName, GenericObjectType& shaderType,
>   String& shaderFormat, String& defines, Boolean& disableOptimizations,
>   String& flags, String& FileGPUdisassemblyContents, String&
>   LiveGPUdisassemblyContents)

[image: Screenshot]
I am developing a game engine based on Direct3d 11. I am creating a debug device and using the following flags to compile the shaders -

```
DWORD dwShaderFlags = D3DCOMPILE_ENABLE_STRICTNESS |   D3DCOMPILE_PACK_MATRIX_ROW_MAJOR ; 
dwShaderFlags |= D3DCOMPILE_DEBUG | D3DCOMPILE_SKIP_OPTIMIZATION | D3DCOMPILE_PREFER_FLOW_CONTROL ;
```

Working on windows 10 64 bit VS 2015 update3 with the windows 10 sdk (I tried retargeting sdk to win8.1 but still no luck). If it matters I also have VS 2013 update5 with win8.1 sdk installed on my system.

I never faced any problems with HLSL debugging before on windows 7. And this is the first time I am trying HLSL debugging in visual graphics debugger after installing windows 10. 
I have also tried reinstalling visual studio 2015 twice but it didn't worked.

Comment: Not really an answer, but i would suggest to you to get as far as possible from VSGD, You will have more luck with RenderDoc.

Comment: I use renderdoc too but HLSL debugging in VSGD is something that saves alot of time specially debugging fairly big and complex shaders.

Comment: Hi, I work on VSGD. Would it be possible to share out a shader file that shows this issue? Doesn't look like an issue that I've seen before and having a repro shader file would help greatly with debugging.

Comment: Hi @IanHuff thanks for your response. Here's the link to zip containing GBuffer.HLSL & its header files. [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iwxwceye0qk2ca8/ShadersForStackOverflowBugReport.zip?dl=0)

It would be a huge help if you guys can fix it or suggest something because debugging big shaders via VSGD HLSL debugging saves a lot of time.

(Also sorry for super late response I almost gave up on this and I am new to stack overflow so I think I missed turning on the email alerts.)

Comment: After the latest windows October updates its working again.
Thanks guys